# Multiple forms in a single page using flask and WTForms

Tags: forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I have multiple form on the same page that send post request to same handler
in flask.

I am generating forms using wtforms.

what is the best way to identify which form is submitted ?

I am currently using `action="?form=oneform"`. I think there should be some better method 
to achieve the same?

Answer (score 118):

The solution above have a **validation bug**, when one form cause a validation error, both forms display an error message. I change the order of `if` to solve this problem.

First, define your multiple `SubmitField` with different names, like this:

```
class Form1(Form):
    name = StringField('name')
    submit1 = SubmitField('submit')

class Form2(Form):
    name = StringField('name')
    submit2 = SubmitField('submit')

....
```

Then add a filter in `view.py`:

```
....
form1 = Form1()
form2 = Form2()
....

if form1.submit1.data and form1.validate(): # notice the order 
....
if form2.submit2.data and form2.validate(): # notice the order 
....
```

**Now the problem was solved.**

If you want to dive into it, then continue read.

Here is `validate_on_submit()`:

```
def validate_on_submit(self):
    """
    Checks if form has been submitted and if so runs validate. This is
    a shortcut, equivalent to ``form.is_submitted() and form.validate()``
    """
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
```

And here is `is_submitted()`:

```
def is_submitted():
    """Consider the form submitted if there is an active request and
    the method is ``POST``, ``PUT``, ``PATCH``, or ``DELETE``.
    """
    return _is_submitted()  # bool(request) and request.method in SUBMIT_METHODS
```

When you call `form.validate_on_submit()`, it check if form is submitted by the HTTP method no matter which submit button was clicked. So the little trick above is just add a filter (to check if submit has data, i.e., `form1.submit1.data`).

Besides, we change the order of `if`, so when we click one submit, **it only call `validate()` to this form**, preventing the validation error for both form.

The story isn't over yet. Here is `.data`:

```
@property
def data(self):
    return dict((name, f.data) for name, f in iteritems(self._fields))
```

It return a dict with field name(key) and field data(value), however, **our two form submit button has same name `submit`(key)!**

When we click the first submit button(in form1), the call from `form1.submit1.data` return a dict like this:

```
temp = {'submit': True}
```

There is no doubt when we call `if form1.submit.data:`, it return `True`.

When we click the second submit button(in form2), the call to `.data` in `if form1.submit.data:` add a key-value in dict **first**, then the call from `if form2.submit.data:` add another key-value, in the end, the dict will like this:

```
temp = {'submit': False, 'submit': True}
```

Now we call `if form1.submit.data:`, it return `True`, even if the submit button we clicked was in form2.

That's why we need to define this two `SubmitField` with different names. By the way, thanks for reading(to here)!

### Update

There is another way to handle multiple forms on one page. You can **use multiple views** to handle forms. For example:

```
...
@app.route('/')
def index():
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    login_form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('index.html', register_form=register_form, login_form=login_form)

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    login_form = LoginForm()

    if register_form.validate_on_submit():
        ...  # handle the register form
    # render the same template to pass the error message
    # or pass `form.errors` with `flash()` or `session` then redirect to /
    return render_template('index.html', register_form=register_form, login_form=login_form)


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    login_form = LoginForm()

    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        ...  # handle the login form
    # render the same template to pass the error message
    # or pass `form.errors` with `flash()` or `session` then redirect to /
    return render_template('index.html', register_form=register_form, login_form=login_form)
```

In the template (index.html), you need to render both forms and set the `action` attribute to target view:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post">
    {{ register_form.username }}
    {{ register_form.password }}
    {{ register_form.email }}
</form>

<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
    {{ login_form.username }}
    {{ login_form.password }}
</form>
```

Comment: IMHO the UPDATE is the best answer. (but `methods=['POST']` seems to be missing in the `@app.route`)

Comment: I used your 1st method but the lines form1.submit1.data and forn2.submit2.data always return false. how to handle it?

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan Maybe you can create a new question, include the related code, then post a link here.

Comment: Second the UPDATE as the best answer. And if anyone wonders, you can actually have all functionality underneath the route('/')—as long as you remember to add the curly bracket parts in form action. You don't need separate routes for login and register, even if this is a nice feature when it comes to register/login pages. But, there are times when you want to put a plethora of different forms on the same page and don't want to bother with massive amounts of routes.

Comment: This also fixed my issue of validation error messages not appearing. Thank you. The easiest solution for me was to do `if form.submit.data and form.validate()` and ensure that the `SubmitField`s had different names.

Comment: Like @Sivaramakrishnan, I also used the 1st method but the lines form1.submit1.data and form2.submit2.data always return false.  No one in the comments has confirmed that the 1st method works.  As the accepted answer, the issue with the 1st method ought to be addressed here, not on a new question as Grey proposed.

Comment: The first method works perfectly for me. @GreyLi mentions 'note the order'. You must begin with `form1.submit1.data` and `form1.validate()` sequentially. Same thing with `form2`. I noticed that a change of the order caused CSRF token to miss.

Comment: @user3661992 do you have an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 67):

I've been using a combination of two flask snippets. [The first adds a prefix to a form](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2010/9/12/flask-wtf-multiple-form-per-view/#d8cfeff63b89d028919d4617ed642d15) and then you check for the prefix with validate_on_submit(). [I use also Louis Roché's template to determine what buttons are pushed in a form](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/11/29/is-there-a-proper-way-to-determine-what-button-was-pushed-on-a-form/#6f3ebc1be73eb7c377b782bf943725e5).

**To quote Dan Jacob:**

Example:

```
form1 = FormA(prefix="form1")
form2 = FormB(prefix="form2")
form3 = FormC(prefix="form3")
```

Then, add a hidden field (or just check a submit field):

```
if form1.validate_on_submit() and form1.submit.data:
```

**To quote Louis Roché's:**

I have in my template :

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Cancel">
```

And to figure out which button was passed server side I have in my views.py file:

```
if request.form['btn'] == 'Save':
    something0
else:
    something1
```

Comment: Notice the order as said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739863/564979

Comment: The provided links are outdated.

Comment: This is the best answer for this question IMO !

Answer (score 27):

A simple way is to have different names for different submit fields. For an
example:

forms.py：

```
class Login(Form):

    ...
    login = SubmitField('Login')


class Register(Form):

    ...
    register = SubmitField('Register')
```

views.py:

```
@main.route('/')
def index():

    login_form = Login()
    register_form = Register()


    if login_form.validate_on_submit() and login_form.login.data:
        print "Login form is submitted"

    elif register_form.validate_on_submit() and register_form.register.data:
        print "Register form is submitted"

    ...
```

Comment: small correction `if login.validate_on_submit() and login_form.login.data:` should be `if login_form.validate_on_submit() and login_form.login.data:`

Comment: @Hieu Thanks. So the `SubmitField('textHere')` specifies that 'textHere' is the value for the name attribute of the <form> tag? Like so: `<form name='Login'>` corresponds to `SubmitField('Login')`.

Answer (score 11):

As the other answers, I also assign a unique name for each submit button, for each form on the page.

Then, the flask web action looks like below - note the `formdata` and `obj` parameters, which help to **init / preserve** the form fields accordingly:

```
@bp.route('/do-stuff', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def do_stuff():
    result = None

    form_1 = None
    form_2 = None
    form_3 = None

    if "submit_1" in request.form:
        form_1 = Form1()
        result = do_1(form_1)
    elif "submit_2" in request.form:
        form_2 = Form2()
        result = do_2(form_2)
    elif "submit_3" in request.form:
        form_3 = Form3()
        result = do_3(form_3)

    if result is not None:
        return result

    # Pre-populate not submitted forms with default data.
    # For the submitted form, leave the fields as they were.

    if form_1 is None:
        form_1 = Form1(formdata=None, obj=...)
    if form_2 is None:
        form_2 = Form2(formdata=None, obj=...)
    if form_3 is None:
        form_3 = Form3(formdata=None, obj=...)

    return render_template("page.html", f1=form_1, f2=form_2, f3=form_3)


def do_1(form):
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Success 1")
        return redirect(url_for(".do-stuff"))


def do_2(form):
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Success 2")
        return redirect(url_for(".do-stuff"))

def do_3(form):
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("Success 3")
        return redirect(url_for(".do-stuff"))
```

Comment: This method works the best of all presented. All other methods technically works too but causes raising of validation errors in forms where wasn't intended. Basically it causes desired behavior of `form not "clicked" being ignored/dead/not interfering`. Thanks!

Comment: What about the ''GET" request? How do you differentiate between getting two get request of the different forms, so that one is picked over the other?

Answer (score 7):

I haven't used WTForms but should work regardless. This is a very quick and simple answer; all you need to do is use different values for the submit button. You can then just do a different def based on each.

In **index.html**:

```
    <div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('do_stuff')}}" method="POST">
            <h1>Plus</h1>
            <input type = "number" id = "add_num1" name = "add_num1" required><label>Number 1</label><br>
            <input type = "number" id = "add_num2" name = "add_num2" required><label>Number 2</label><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "submit_add" name = "submit" ><br>
        </form>
        <p>Answer: {{ add }}</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('do_stuff')}}" method="POST">
            <h1>Minus</h1>
            <input type = "number" id = "min_num1" name = "min_num1" required><label>Number 1</label><br>
            <input type = "number" id = "min_num2" name = "min_num2" required><label>Number 2</label><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "submit_min" name = "submit"><br>
        </form>
        <p>Answer: {{ minus }}</p>
    </div>
```

in **app.py**:

```
@app.route('/',methods=["POST"])
def do_stuff():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add = ""
        minus = ""
        if request.form['submit'] == 'submit_add':
            num1 = request.form['add_num1']
            num2 = request.form['add_num2']
            add = int(num1) + int(num2)

        if request.form['submit'] == 'submit_min':
            num1 = request.form['min_num1']
            num2 = request.form['min_num2']
            minus = int(num1) - int(num2)
    return render_template('index.html', add = add, minus = minus)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well here is a simple trick

Assume you Have

> Form1, Form2, and index

---

```
Form1  <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('index',formid=1) }}">

Form2  <form  method="post" action="{{ url_for('index',formid=2) }}">
```

---

Now In index

```
@bp.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    formid = request.args.get('formid', 1, type=int)
    if formremote.validate_on_submit() and formid== 1:
        return "Form One"
    if form.validate_on_submit() and formid== 2:
        return "Form Two"
```

Answer (score 4):

I normally use a hidden tag that works as an identifier.

Here is an example:

```
class Form1(Form):
    identifier = StringField()
    name = StringField('name')
    submit = SubmitField('submit')

class Form2(Form):
    identifier = StringField()
    name = StringField('name')
    submit = SubmitField('submit')
```

Then you can add a filter in view.py:

```
....
form1 = Form1()
form2 = Form2()
....

if form1.identifier.data == 'FORM1' and form1.validate_on_submit():
....
if form2.identifier.data == 'FORM2' and form2.validate_on_submit():
....
```

and finally in the HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  {{ form1.indentifier(hidden=True, value='FORM1') }}
</form>
<form method="POST">
  {{ form2.indentifier(hidden=True, value='FORM2') }}
</form>
```

If you do it like this in the if statement it will check what was the identifier and if its equal it will run the form stuff you have in your code.

Comment: I do this too, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Example: Multiple WTForm in single html page

**app.py**

```
"""
Purpose Create multiple form on single html page.

Here we are having tow forms first is Employee_Info and CompanyDetails
"""
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, FloatField, validators
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret'

class EmployeeInfo(FlaskForm):
    """
    EmployeeInfo class will have Name,Dept
    """
    fullName = StringField('Full Name',[validators.InputRequired()])
    dept = StringField('Department',[validators.InputRequired()])

class CompanyDetails(FlaskForm):
    """
    CompanyDetails will have yearOfExp. 
    """
    yearsOfExp = IntegerField('Year of Experiece',[validators.InputRequired()]) 


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'] )
def index():
    """
    View will render index.html page.
    If form is validated then showData.html will load the employee or company data.
    """
    companydetails = CompanyDetails()
    employeeInfo = EmployeeInfo()

    if companydetails.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('showData.html', form = companydetails)

    if employeeInfo.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('showData.html', form1 = employeeInfo)   

    return render_template('index.html',form1 = employeeInfo, form = companydetails)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True, port =8092)
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h4> Company Details </h4>

        <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('index')}}">

            {{ form.csrf_token }}

            {{ form.yearsOfExp.label }} {{ form.yearsOfExp }}       

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <hr>
        <h4> Employee Form </h4>

        <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('index')}}" >

            {{ form1.csrf_token }}

            {{ form1.fullName.label }} {{ form1.fullName }}

            {{ form1.dept.label }} {{ form1.dept }}

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**showData.html**

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body>
        {% if form1 %}
        <h2> Employee Details </h2>
            {{ form1.fullName.data }}
            {{ form1.dept.data }}
        {% endif %}
        {% if form %}
            <h2> Company Details </h2>
                {{ form.yearsOfExp.data }}      
        {% endif %}     
    </body>
</html>
```