# Multiple buttons on a flask webapp?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm making my first webapp using python and flask, it is a simple calculator but I'm currently stuck trying to use more than one button. At the beginning it was abe just to show a graph, here is the python code:

```
class FormulaForm(Form):
    formula = StringField('formula')
    graph = SubmitField('graph')

@app.route('/')
def calculate():
    form = FormulaForm()
    formula = request.args.get('formula','')
    points = mp.make_points(formula,0,7)
    comp = make_plot(points[0],points[1])
    return render_template('index.html',the_script=comp[0],the_div=comp[1],form=form)
```

And here is the html code:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <br />
        {{ form.formula }}
    <br />
        {{ form.graph }}
</form>
```

So far so good. But I don't know how to add more functionality, for example I would like to add a button that shows the formula evaluated at some value x. I tried adding an extra inputfield and an extra button in the form, something like this:

```
class FormFormula(Form):
    formula = StringField('formula')
    graph = SubmitField('graph')
    evaluate = StringField('evaluate_at')
    evaluate = SubmitField('evaluate')
```

But then I don't know how to make the view handle two different actions.
I think I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290142/multiple-forms-in-a-single-page-using-flask-and-wtforms) but it only works when the method is "POST" and that makes the page reload which I don't want. So, is there a way to use multiple buttons in the same view?

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload you'll have to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/start' ,methods=['POST'])
def stop():
    "process done here"
    return Something
```

Your app.py like this and and html file this

```
    <script src="static/js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start").click(function(event){
    $.post(
        "/start",
        function(data) {
            window.alert(data);         
            }
        );      
            });
    });

</script>

<button id ="start" type="button" value = "Load Data">Start</button>
```