# multiple forms in one page Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have a website where I gave 2 different forms. Here is my HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} 
Home page
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="pt-5">
<form action="data" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv, .xlsx, .xls" />
   <input type="submit" name="form1" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
<div class="pt-5">
   <form action="data" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file1" accept=".csv, .xlsx, .xls" />
      <input type="file" name="file2" accept=".csv, .xlsx, .xls" />
      <input type="submit" name="form2" value="Merge"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

Both forms uploads files, the first form uploads just one file while the other form should Merge two files. Now both will actually to the same page. How can I differentiate between them? I searched and I have come across solutions like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if "form1" in request.form:
        print("form1")
    elif "form2" in request.form:
        print("form2")
```

But this does not work for me, how can I know from which form my request is coming from? Thanks.

**EDIT**

The solution I provided above works now, I did not know why it did not work before...

Comment: I think You have to specify the `action` parameter in html and then have it redirect to the same route but with some kind of a variable that way You can differentiate between forms

Comment: it would be easier if you create two post routes for forms, like for form 1 `<form action="/data1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and form 2 ``<form action="/data2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and access the file as `request.form.get('file1')` and so on

Comment: Isnt there a better way to do so? something like the soultion I did above but did not work. This does not seem so effective..

Comment: @Epsi95 but then I do have two different routes data1 and data2. Can't I just have the same route and still achieve it? It feels like Flask must have done something to acheive what I am looking for without createing many routes. What if I have 5-6 forms in one page. Then I need a new route for each form? not so effective in my opinion..

Comment: there is nothing fancy here, whenever you are making form, under the hood it is just `post`ing some data to the specific url, the best you can do is to create one hidden fileld in your form, and in your flask you can check which form it to extract values like `<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="1">` and keep the route same. Then in your code you can do like `request.form.get('formid') == '1')`@MohammedAbdu

Comment: @Epsi95 I will try it out

Comment: @MohammedAbdu check some of the responses in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290142/multiple-forms-in-a-single-page-using-flask-and-wtforms)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using different attribute `action` is easier like below.

```html
<form action="upload_1" method="post"> ... </form>
```

Comment: is there no other way to achieve it without creating different rountes?

Comment: @MohammedAbdu I found that `'form1' in request.form` works for me.

Comment: please provide the code that worked for you

Comment: @MohammedAbdu It seems it is exactly the same as yours

Comment: for some reason it worked now, don't know why it did not work before...

Comment: @MohammedAbdu Magic

Comment: Must be yeah haha